# Large Formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013,

I apply 2 way the Large Formula VBA, but not working, what i am wrong, i don't know

```
Sub Macro1()

'1st Table Dim statement ---> Declares variables

Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

lRow = Range("D5").End(xlDown).Row

lCol = Range("C5").End(xlToRight).Column

'Column Count in Number

Dim k As Long, m As Long

k = Range("C5", Range("C5").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

'Row Count in Number

m = Range("D6", Range("D6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range(Range("D5").Offset(1, k + 3), Range("D5").Offset(m, k + 3))


Range("D5").Offset(2, 1 + 3).Formula = "=LARGE(" & MyRange & ",1)"

'And

'=(LARGE($I$6:$I$12,1)-I7)/2

Range("D5").Offset(2, 1 + 3).Formula = "=(LARGE(" & MyRange & ",1)-" & Range("D5").Offset(1, k + 3) & ")/2"

End Sub
```

Kindy help me and Thanks for advance

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the addresses of the ranges to your formula:

```
Range("D5").Offset(2, 1 + 3).Formula = "=(LARGE(" & MyRange.address & ",1)-" & Range("D5").Offset(1, k + 3).address & ")/2"
```

Comment: Yes!!! Successfully work, thanks for your support